# What is a good way to copy and mutate list items in Scala?

Tags: scala

If I have a list of objects with interesting fields that I want to copy to a new list of new (and slightly different objects) objects, how to I go about it?

Say you have two different classes:

```
class Person(name: String, surname: String)

class Technician(firstName: String, lastName: String, title: String)
```

Now assume you have a list of Technicians, what is a good way to create a list of Persons from that list of Technicians? Persons don't have a title field, so that can be ignored, and the firstName and lastName fields from technician needs to be mapped to name and surname for each new Person in the new list.

Comment: Generally you should make Technician extend Person, if you are able. Thus you get it for free if you call asInstanceOf[Person]. If you are not able, I would suggest the same solution as drexin.

Comment: Thanks @T.Grottker. I completely agree that it would have been ideal, but in this case I can't do that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `map` operation of the `List` class:

```
xs.map { t => new Person(t.firstName, t.lastName) }
```

As the name says, it maps all the objects in one list to the result of the block and returns them as a new list.

Comment: @JacobusR: You even used the magic word `map` in your question :-)